# How many iterations will it take to evaluate the sum of two binary strings without using arithmetic operations?

Tags: python-3.x, bit-manipulation

I understand the working of the following code but how do I get number of iterations required to reach the answer?

Given that length of binary strings are upto **10^5**.

Code:

```
def fun(a,b):
    while(b!=0):
        carry = a&b
        a = a^b
        b = carry<<1
    return a
```

Here **a and b are non negative integers**. It is pointless to convert binary strings to into decimal form as integers would be very large (2**(10**5)).

**EDIT :**
Adding a counter will not help as I will have to convert the strings in decimal forms and store it in variables **a** and **b** which is not feasible and size of strings are upto 10^5.

Comment: Add a counter variable within the loop?

Comment: @cricket_007 That will be useful only if I will be able to convert binary strings in decimal form, in this case it is not possible as decimal form would be very large.

Comment: 10^5 bits isn't *that* much, you can store those numbers. "In decimal" isn't really the case, Python integers aren't inherently decimal, they're just .. integers. That they usually get printed in decimal is not a reflection of what they really *are*, nor of how they are implemented, it is just a particular visualization.

Comment: @harold how do you suggest to solve this question then?

Comment: @Ishaan007 I don't have a specific suggestion, there is probably a trick and I don't know the trick. If there was no trick there would be no point in setting this problem for competitive programming (it is for that competition, right?)

Comment: @harold yeah man. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Counter seemed to work for this person https://stackoverflow.com/q/59233751/2308683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is theoretic answer, but it may help.

You'd expect number of iterations equal to number of bits in strings in worst case:

```
    a: 01111...1111
    b: 00000...0001
1st:---------------
    a: 01111...1110
    b: 00000...0010
2nd:---------------
    a: 01111...1100
    b: 00000...0100
etc...
```

Here you see carry propagating from lsb to msb through whole string.

In general case number of iterations equal to 1 plus the longest carry propagation path, which starts with a[i]=b[i]=1 and continues with a[i]=1 b[i]=0 or a[i]=0 b[i]=1.

An example:

```
    a: 00101100100110 tooks 5 iterations:
    b: 00011011101110
         \_/\__/ \/   as there are carry paths of 3, 4 and 2 bits, longest is 4.
1st------------------
    a: 00110111001000
    b: 00010001001100
2nd------------------
    a: 00100110000100
    b: 00100010010000
3rd------------------
    a: 00000100010100
    b: 01000100100000
4th------------------
    a: 00000000110100
    b: 10001000000000
5th------------------
    a: 10001000110100
    b: 00000000000000
```

(If you interested in lower number of iterations, study fast carry propagation algorithm.)